# Subclass of custom State object cannot be used in createState

Tags: dart, flutter

I am attempting to separate my state from my views as this tutorial describes: https://blog.usejournal.com/easily-navigate-through-your-flutter-code-by-separating-view-and-view-model-240026191106. Unfortunately, it looks like Flutter is expecting `createState` to return an object that extends `State<>` directly and not a subclass of another class.

Exception:

`StatefulWidget.createState must return a subtype of State<RateAdvisorScreen>. The createState function for RateAdvisorScreen returned a state of type RateAdvisorView, which is not a subtype of State<RateAdvisorScreen>, violating the contract for createState.`

Here are my class definitions:

`class RateAdvisorScreen extends StatefulWidget
abstract class RateAdvisorState extends State<RateAdvisorScreen>
class RateAdvisorView extends RateAdvisorState`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Additional information**

This only seems to happen when the view class has been separated into its own file. If all three classes have been defined in the same file, there are no issues.

Comment: This works just fine for me, are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else?

Comment: If I place all of the classes into the same file, it works. When I separate the view into a different file, I get this error.

Comment: getting this error too & not when in a different file, did you find out why?